# Problem targeting a certain elements using each

Tags: jquery

Be nice, I am still learning, but I am playing with going through instances where I have several div's or list items and I have to use **each** to do the same function within the individual elements, I have been trying to use **parent** and **prev** and all sorts of things but as you can see in my [FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/kellyhawker/vt9ezr71/15/) for some reason I can only get the source of the last image, what I want to achieve is getting a thumbnail from each of the sections.

HTML

```js
$('.eaWkArticle').find('img.wp-post-image').each(function() {
     var xx = $(this).attr('src');
     $('.headerBg').css({'background' : 'url(' + xx + ') no-repeat center', '-webkit-background-size' : 'cover', '-moz-background-size' : 'cover', '-o-background-size': 'cover', 'background-size' : 'cover'}); 
});
```

```css
.eaWkArticle { display:none; }
.headerBg { display:block; width:100px; height:100px; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="container">
<li class="listItem">

<span class="headerBg"></span>
<span class="headline subheader">Heading</span>
<p class="date">4/8/2020</p>
<a class="wkLink linkbuttons">Read More</a>
<div class="eaWkArticle">
<div>
<div>
<img src="https://homepages.cae.wisc.edu/~ece533/images/airplane.png" class="wp-post-image" />
</div>
</div>
</div>

</li>
<li class="listItem">

<span class="headerBg"></span>
<span class="headline subheader">Heading</span>
<p class="date">4/9/2020</p>
<a class="wkLink linkbuttons">Read More</a>
<div class="eaWkArticle">
<div>
<div>
<img src="https://homepages.cae.wisc.edu/~ece533/images/baboon.png" class="wp-post-image" />
</div>
</div>
</div>

</li>
<li class="listItem">

<span class="headerBg"></span>
<span class="headline subheader">Heading</span>
<p class="date">4/10/2020</p>
<a class="wkLink linkbuttons">Read More</a>
<div class="eaWkArticle">
<div>
<div>
<img src="https://homepages.cae.wisc.edu/~ece533/images/boat.png" class="wp-post-image" />
</div>
</div>
</div>

</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: See my answer. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have looped image finding inside `.eaWkArticle` but there is only one image inside this div. So, you have to select image and loop through around it and find the `.headerBg` element to its closest `li` element.

Please see below for working demo code-

```js
$('img.wp-post-image').each(function(i, item) {
  var xx = $(item).attr('src');
  $(item).closest('li.listItem').find('.headerBg').css({
    'background': 'url(' + xx + ') no-repeat center',
    '-webkit-background-size': 'cover',
    '-moz-background-size': 'cover',
    '-o-background-size': 'cover',
    'background-size': 'cover'
  });
});
```

```css
.eaWkArticle {
  display: none;
}

.headerBg {
  display: block;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="container">
  <li class="listItem">

    <span class="headerBg"></span>
    <span class="headline subheader">Heading</span>
    <p class="date">4/8/2020</p>
    <a class="wkLink linkbuttons">Read More</a>
    <div class="eaWkArticle">
      <div>
        <div>
          <img src="https://homepages.cae.wisc.edu/~ece533/images/airplane.png" class="wp-post-image" />
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

  </li>
  <li class="listItem">

    <span class="headerBg"></span>
    <span class="headline subheader">Heading</span>
    <p class="date">4/9/2020</p>
    <a class="wkLink linkbuttons">Read More</a>
    <div class="eaWkArticle">
      <div>
        <div>
          <img src="https://homepages.cae.wisc.edu/~ece533/images/baboon.png" class="wp-post-image" />
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

  </li>
  <li class="listItem">

    <span class="headerBg"></span>
    <span class="headline subheader">Heading</span>
    <p class="date">4/10/2020</p>
    <a class="wkLink linkbuttons">Read More</a>
    <div class="eaWkArticle">
      <div>
        <div>
          <img src="https://homepages.cae.wisc.edu/~ece533/images/boat.png" class="wp-post-image" />
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Thanks so much, I was trying parent and prev but didn't look into closest.

Comment: My Pleasure :). If my answer helps, you can upvote it too :P @webmonkey237